# Ratio dependent diffy q's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine if the following are ratio dependent

I know $x'=f(\frac x t)$ is required for ratio dependent.

The ones in question are.

$$x' = \frac{2x+3t} {4x-5t}$$

$$x' = \frac{2x^2+3t^2} {4x-5t}$$

I'm leaning toward them not being. The reason being is that from what I understand is if they were

$x'=\frac {2x+3x} {4t-5t}$ it would be in $x'=\frac x t$

$x'=\frac {2x^2+3x^2}{4t-5t}$ would be in $x'=\frac x t$

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Comment: lol @ "diffy q's"

Answer (score 0):

$$x' = \frac{2x+3t} {4x-5t}= \frac{2+3\frac tx} {4-5\frac tx} \equiv f(\frac tx)$$

$$x'=\frac {2x^2+3t^2}{4x-5t}= \frac {2x+3t \frac tx}{4-5\frac tx}= x \left(\frac {2+3 (\frac tx)^2}{4-5\frac tx} \right) \equiv x g(\frac tx)$$

so the first one is ratio dependent but the second is not.

Comment: thank you. I understood what I was doing wrong.